# 192.168.1.252 seems to be a local IP, but it's not local?

Tags: networking, routes, ping, nmap, traceroute

I nmapped to an ip address in order to get what kind of network and internet connection do i have. I thought the ip i nmapped (192.168.1.252) should be local, but it seems it's not. I'm still trying to get what's going on here, so i hope you can help me.

Well i'm sure I'm not using proxy. My connection information log is here:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:77:37:5b:75:20  
          inet addr:192.168.254.237  Bcast:192.168.254.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be77:37ff:fe5b:7520/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:231318 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:745108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:163736713 (163.7 MB)  TX bytes:65020817 (65.0 MB)
```

My nmap command and log is down here:

```
nmap -v 192.168.1.252 --traceroute

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-20 23:21 EET
Initiating Ping Scan at 23:21
Scanning 192.168.1.252 [4 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 23:21, 0.04s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 23:21
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 23:21, 0.18s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 23:21
Scanning 192.168.1.252 [1000 ports]
Increasing send delay for 192.168.1.252 from 0 to 5 due to 36 out of 118 dropped probes since last increase.
Discovered open port 179/tcp on 192.168.1.252
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 23:21, 9.05s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Initiating Traceroute at 23:21
Completed Traceroute at 23:21, 1.04s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 11 hosts. at 23:21
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 11 hosts. at 23:21, 4.01s elapsed
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.252
Host is up (0.037s latency).
Not shown: 989 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
20/tcp   filtered ftp-data
21/tcp   filtered ftp
22/tcp   filtered ssh
23/tcp   filtered telnet
49/tcp   filtered tacacs
80/tcp   filtered http
179/tcp  open     bgp
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
646/tcp  filtered ldp
5060/tcp filtered sip
6881/tcp filtered bittorrent-tracker

TRACEROUTE (using port 995/tcp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   4.00 ms  192.168.254.254
2   4.90 ms  172.16.172.2
3   9.52 ms  10.36.1.1
4   10.32 ms 172.16.26.1
5   19.69 ms 212.174.242.93.dynamic.ttnet.com.tr (212.174.242.93)
6   29.07 ms 95.2.128.14.dynamic.ttnet.com.tr (95.2.128.14)
7   34.86 ms 95.2.128.13.dynamic.ttnet.com.tr (95.2.128.13)
8   31.90 ms afyon-t2-1-afyon-t3-1.turktelekom.com.tr.220.212.81.in-addr.arpa (81.212.220.97)
9   41.11 ms ulus-t2-3-afyon-t2-1.turktelekom.com.tr.206.212.81.in-addr.arpa (81.212.206.125)
10  31.20 ms ulus-t2-1-ulus-t2-3.turktelekom.com.tr.197.212.81.in-addr.arpa (81.212.197.197)
11  31.60 ms 192.168.1.252

Read data files from: /usr/share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.39 seconds
Raw packets sent: 1096 (48.200KB) | Rcvd: 1009 (40.656KB)
```

Comment: What's the address and netmask on your interface?  "Local" is defined by the netmask.

Comment: you're right. I just edited the post with ifconfig -a data

Comment: @user3124100 You are asking why a class C private IP address is reachable through the Internet, right?

Comment: @CarloCannas that's right. Since my netmask is /24, 192.168.254.x is in the same network with me and 192.168.1.x is not. But how come I access an IP that is assigned to be a local network? And what if for those their local ip address is 192.168.1.x, how do they access this IP? Isn't 192.168.1.252 some local ip for they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Local" is defined by the combination of interface IP address and netmask.  With a 24-bit netmask, 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.254.0 are definitely different networks.

[Here is a good explanation of netmasks](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/netmask.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is on a secured network and not your home network right? If thats the case then what you will get is your machine info not network info. Since you are part of a network on Server system, remote login into that server and try the same.

Comment: Well actually my ISP provides some weird kind of internet access. They've put an antenna on my roof, which is pointed somewhere away like 8 miles. It has only one slot on it, and it's a usual ethernet cable. That cable comes into the house, and connected to a plug with an adapter. The adapter has 2 ethernet ports on it, one is going to that antenna on the roof, and one is going to my computer. (or my access point, doen't matter.)

My purpose on asking this question was actually to understand what kind of network do I have, in order to connect my computer with ssh outside the local network.